# Hibernate saveOrUpdate behavior

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Does anyone know how Hibernate knows whether to INSERT or to UPDATE a value in the database when `session.saveOrUpdate()` is called?

So far, I have only determined that it is not dependent on the information in the cache, and that the existence of the entity in the database is determined by the primary key.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When you use `.saveOrUpdate()` Hibernate will check if the object is transient (it has no identifier property) and if so it will make it persistent by generating it the identifier and assigning it to session. If the object has an identifier already it will perform `.update()`.

From the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-makingpersistent):

saveOrUpdate() does the following:

- if the object is already persistent
  in this session, do nothing
- if another object associated with the
  session has the same identifier,
  throw an exception
- if the object has no identifier
  property, save() it
- if the object's identifier has the
  value assigned to a newly
  instantiated object, save() it
- if the object is versioned by a
  "version" or "timestamp", and the
  version property value is the same
  value assigned to a newly
  instantiated object, save() it
  otherwise update() the object

Comment: "if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save()" I created a `clone()` of a detached object (keeping the same identifier), and modified a value. Hibernate `update()` the Object. under which category does it fall?

Comment: Sorry, fixed my answer with correct formatting. I guess under "if another object associated with the session has the same identifier, throw an exception" ?!

Comment: I don't get any exception, because the first object is Detached via `session.evict()`.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps it is helpful to quote the Hibernate bible ([Java Persistence with Hibernate, 2nd ed.](https://www.manning.com/books/java-persistence-with-hibernate-second-edition), page 528):

> More experienced Hibernate users use `saveOrUpdate()` exclusively; it's much easier to let Hibernate decide what is new and what is old, especially in a more complex network of objects with mixed state. The only (not really serious) disadvantage of exclusive `saveOrUpdate()` is that it sometimes can't guess whether an instance is old or new without firing a `SELECT` at the database - for example, when a class is mapped with a natural composite key and no version or timestamp property.
>
> How does Hibernate detect which instances are old and which are new? A range of options is available. Hibernate assumes that an instance is an unsaved transient instance if:
>
> - The identifier property is `null`.
> - The version or timestamp property (if it exists) is `null`.
> - A new instance of the same persistent class, created by Hibernate internally, has the same database identifier values as the given instance.
> - You supply an `unsaved-value` in the mapping document for the class, and the value of the identifier property matches. The `unsaved-value` attribute is also available for version and timestamp mapping elements.
> - Entity data with the same identifier value isn't in the second-level cache.
> - You supply an implementation or `org.hibernate.Interceptor` and return `Boolean.TRUE` from `Interceptor.isUnsaved()` after checking the instance in your code.

Answer (score 2):

As stated [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-saveorupdate), `saveOrUpdate` either saves a transient instance by generating a new identifier or updates/reattaches the detached instances associated with its current identifier. More specifically it does:

- if the object is already persistent in this session, do nothing
- if another object associated with the session has the same identifier, throw an exception
- if the object has no identifier property, `save()` it
- if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it
- if the object is versioned by a `<version>` or `<timestamp>`, and the version property value is
- the same value assigned to a newly instantiated object, `save()` it
- otherwise `update()` the object

Answer (score 1):

This is done based on the value of the primary key. If the primary key is undefined, it's value will default to 0 for numeric surrogate keys and `save` will be performed. If the primary key is filled out, it will invoke an `update`.

Comment: This is incorrect, for me saveOrUpdate does not update even if I provide a update with the same primary key.

Comment: @Siddharth: It is hard to tell what's the issue in your code whithout seeing the code. I was using Hibernate for 8 years now and saveOrUpdate worked just fine for me.

Comment: I could only get it working with the update = true, insert = false attributes in the hbm.

Answer (score 1):

If someone not really understood in theory then there is a code

```
MyModel sent = myDao.myDaoImpl(id); 

if(sent == null){                        
    sent = **new MyModel();** // new Object
    sent.setXX(id);
    sent.setYY("Yes");
    sent.setDate(new Date());
    myDao.saveOrUpdate(sent); // Insert will be called
} else if(! "Yes".equalsIgnoreCase(sent.getFlag())) {
    sent.setXX("Yes");
    sent.setDate(new Date());
    myDao.saveOrUpdate(sent); // Update will be called
}
```