# Hibernate merge is not querying DB when object is not in persistence context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using:

1. Spring 3.1
2. Spring Data JPA 1.1
3. Hibernate 4.1

I have a problem. I have a standard Spring Data JPA DAO:

```
public interface DnarDao extends JpaRepository<Dnar, Long> {
  // insert Spring Data magic here!
}
```

Here is the `Dnar` code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="req_dnar", schema=SCHEMA)
@Inheritance(strategy=JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="form_type", discriminatorType=STRING, length=64)
public abstract class Dnar {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE, generator="dnar_gen_seq")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="dnar_gen_seq", sequenceName="req_dnar_seq")
  @Column(name=C_DNAR_ID, nullable=false)
  private Long dnarId;

  @Column(name="form_type", nullable=false, length=64)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private FormType formType;
  // remainder omitted
}
```

And an example of an implementation class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="req_dnar_general_lv")
@DiscriminatorValue("GENERAL_LV")
public class GeneralLvDnar extends Dnar {
  //remainder omitted
}
```

Also, here is my Spring config for the Hibernate stuff:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="uRL" value="${JDBC_URL}"/>
  <property name="user" value="${USER_ID}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${PASSWORD}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="packagesToScan">
    <list><value>com/mycomp/domain</value></list>
  </property>
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
     </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.mycomp.dao" />

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

**Round 1 - the problem**

The client of the DAO is the `DnarManagerImpl` class:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public Dnar save(final Dnar dnar) {

  Dnar managedDnar = dnarDao.save(dnar);
  return managedDnar;
}
```

The above code works but it **always** creates a new `dnar` row in the database. I've debugged the Spring Data JPA code, and it appears to be working correctly. For example if I save the same object 3 times, the Hibernate invocations are:

1. `getSession().persist(entity);`
2. `getSession().merge(entity);`
3. `getSession().merge(entity);`

The SQL that Hibernate outputs for the above is:

1. INSERT INTO ...
2. INSERT INTO ...
3. INSERT INTO ...

**Round 2 - a hack fix**

With a bit of experimentation, I found that I can tell the current session that this entity exists by using `dnarDao.findOne(id);`. And this fixes my problem:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public Dnar save(final Dnar dnar) {

  // Hack to get the Dnar in the current persistence context
  if (dnar.getDnarId() != null) {
    dnarDao.findOne(dnar.getDnarId());
  }
  Dnar managedDnar = dnarDao.save(dnar);
  return managedDnar;
}
```

Again the Hibernate session invocations are:

1. `getSession().persist(entity);`
2. `getSession().merge(entity);`
3. `getSession().merge(entity);`

The SQL that Hibernate outputs is now correct:

1. INSERT INTO ...
2. UPDATE ...
3. UPDATE ...

**The Question**

According to the [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1356), this is how `merge()` works:

1. if there is a managed instance with the same identifier currently associated with the persistence context, copy the state of the given object onto the managed instance
2. if there is no managed instance currently associated with the persistence context, try to load it from the database, or create a new managed instance
3. the managed instance is returned
4. the given instance does not become associated with the persistence context, it remains detached and is usually discarded

Clearly, in my example, Item 2 is not occurring. Hibernate is not trying to load this entity from the database. Hibernate **never** outputs a select (exception in my hack fix). Sooo.... Where am I going wrong? I'm sure that Hibernate does work as per the docs, it's just that I've done something foolish.

Comment: in the code: public Dnar save(final Dnar dnar).. how do you obtain the Dnar instance? Since your service method call is @Transactional, it uses the default transaction isolation of the underlying db engine. Have you tried to fiddle with that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is because you do save instead of saveAndFlush. save does not guarantee that the object is inserted into the database, thus Hibernate does 3 inserts.

**EDIT**.

Ok, so save method from the JPA Repository : it is NOT called create or update, because it EITHER updates or creates based on the presence of the primary key - look at the source code.
Also save is supposed to save an Object no matter the state it is in, that is why it is called **save** because it does not care if it is a merge or persist, it going to save the object NO MATTER the state it is in.

One more thing that you are dealing with is object "equality", which in JPA is implemented at the primary key level. If inside the object that you are trying to store you have a ID that matches then one you are passing in => merge, else => persist.

Thus your logic makes (almost) perfect sense. In the first case save does 3 inserts, because the ID(primary key) of the object does NOT exist yet.

In the second case by bringing the ID in the persistent context you do only! the first insert, then the rest are updates.

I could not fully reproduce your test-case because I do not have the time for it :(, but, to me, the thing that you are seeing IS PERFECTLY valid.

I wish some experienced JPA developer would comment too on this question.

Comment: Hi Eugene, unfortunately the same thing occurs with `saveAndFlush()`. Thanks a lot for the answer though!

Comment: @Muel you need to provide the Dnar class., please update your answer with the Dnar code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this code:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public Dnar save(final Dnar dnar) {
  Dnar managedDnar = dnarDao.save(dnar);
  return managedDnar;
}
```

I would think you are actually doing the proper thing if you want to save a newly created object. However, if you are merely modifying an existing one, you should use update. If you obtained that dnar instance out of the session, you know it exists (in the session scope at least), so you could just use update on it. If you have created the object yourself and want to save it in the db, you should use save.

There is a hefty method call that takes care of that for you, called 'saveOrUpdate' which is going to try to either persist an entity by calling save that was not in db previously (based on the absence of the identifier) or will call update if your entity has an id. Your code will then change to this, assuming you have saveOrupdate in your dao. Here is a nice answer in SO that describes the behavior:

[Hibernate saveOrUpdate behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443672/hibernate-saveorupdate-behavior)

```
@Transactional
@Override
public Dnar save(final Dnar dnar) {
   Dnar managedDnar = dnarDao.saveOrUpdate(dnar);
   return managedDnar;
}
```

Comment: I really do not want to rain or your parade, but he is using spring-data-jpa, which does not have a saveOrUpdate. His question is perfectly valid and has very little to do with this answer. Might I suggest that you re-read it?