# There is a way to check if Hibernate method .saveOrUpdate() did an insert or update?

Tags: hibernate

How can I know if Hibernate did an insert or update AFTER run `getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(object);` the method is void!

> saveOrUpdate() does the following:
>
> - if the object is already persistent in this session, do nothing
> - if another object associated with the session has the same identifier, throw an exception
> - if the object has no identifier property, save() it
> - if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly  instantiated object, save() it
> - if the object is versioned by a  or , and the version property value is the same value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it
> - otherwise update() the object

I'm afraid I always have to check if the object already have a 'primary key/id' BEFORE run this method, **is this the only way?** If yes, how can I get the primary key/ID in a generic way?

`Serializable id = session.getIdentifier(entity);` or `Object id = entityManagerFactory.getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(entity);` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Checking the Identifier associated with an entity in the persistence context means we are checking if the entity is in persistent state or not. 
Since u have already referred the documentation i would suggest please have look at this question, 
[Hibernate saveOrUpdate behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443672/hibernate-saveorupdate-behavior) - have a look at Olaf's answer, it explains how it works in short and sweet way.

with JPA 2.0 we have the

> Object id = entityManagerFactory.getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(entity); way of checking.

However your question is tagged for hibernate, so the first one is correct.

> Serializable id = session.getIdentifier(entity);

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  but I ended it by checking the 'id' atributte, which in my case was present in all classes and is in fact the primarykey:  `Field id = entity.getClass().getDeclaredField(id);   id.setAccessible(true);`