# batch saveORupdate using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a batch operation where in i have to either insert or update a record.I want to inser larger number of records so i need to commit batch after batch

1)Insert if new 
2)Update if existing.

I can typically do it using

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
  Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
  session.saveOrUpdat(customer);
  if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
    //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
  }
}

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

The problem is hibernate generates a select before each saveOrUpdate which seems to be a issue.

The primarykey of object is always populated before passing to hibernate.As it primaryKey is never  generated by hibernate using sequencer or anything else.

How can i avoid this exta select for each saveOrupdate?

I dnt want to use stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps that it takes for Hibernate to decide whether to update or insert a record in to database.

```
saveOrUpdate() does the following:

if the object is already persistent in this session, do nothing
if another object associated with the session has the same identifier, throw an exception
if the object has no identifier property, save() it
if the object's identifier has the value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it
if the object is versioned by a <version> or <timestamp>, and the version property value is the same value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it
otherwise update() the object.
```

If in any case there is a conflict and hibernate is not able to decide on what operation to perform it does a select.

Coming to your question, try giving an hint to Hibernate like using the fields like timestamp or version

**Credits** - [Jboss HIbernate Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-saveorupdate), [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21535730)

Comment: Thanks for answering.But it doesnot ans my question.How do i prent hibernate from issueing that extra select .In my case  object with same id may or may already exist in DB(not in session).So hibernate first checks if there is alredy existing object with that id by using that select statement.I want to avoid that.How?

Comment: Create a a field and annotate it with version in your Entity and create a column called version for that particular table. If the version is set to default value then a save happens else an update happens!