# Check duplicate value before insertion using Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unique-key

I am using Spring+Hibernate for my application. I have a few CRUD operations. Before inserting, I need to check if a similar entry is already in the database, if yes it should not be inserted. 
For eg: If I am trying to create a Department, before inserting the row, I should check if a department with the same name already exist or not. If yes, the method returns error message.
Now, I know the unique key constraint can be set on the column to do the check. But, I want to know if there is any other way to do this.

The only way I can think of is first fetching all the departments from the database and check against each object.

Please let me know if there is any other way.

Comment: "I know the unique key constraint can be set on the column to do the check." <-- do that; it is the most efficient way of doing what you want.

Comment: Want to know if the same think can be implemented in the middleware itself.

Comment: It could be but that's a waste; a dedicated database engine will always be faster at doing that.

Answer (score 0):

> The only way I can think of is first fetching all the departments from the database and check against each object.

You don't need to fetch *all* departments form the database. It should be enough to search the database for the department with the name you want to insert. Since the name should have a unique key anyways it should be fast enough.

Comment: Yup, that is fine. Still I need to fetch the value and check it right? I want to know if there is any in-built method t check that. SO that I do not need to add the checks everywhere separately.

Answer (score 0):

If your `@Id` attribute is department name, then the `saveOrUpdate` API of Hibernate will check if  an object with that id is already present in the DB. If so it will update, else it will create a new entry. Hope this should help you. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443672/hibernate-saveorupdate-behavior).

Comment: No, I have an another field deptId whose value is auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try find object from database by "get" method:

```
Cat cat = (Cat) sess.get(Cat.class, id);
```

If received object is null, you can add new.
Also for performance better use query with "count" predicate, for avoid whole object loading.