# SaveOrUpdate if a row is null Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, session, hql

I'm just a bit confused about Hibernate's saveorupdate. for example, if I try to "update" the row with the ADDRESS_TYPE of 'BI', will it be updated or a new row will be inserted?

[image]

Comment: It all depends on if your object has got the identifier field(id field) see this SO post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443672/hibernate-saveorupdate-behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will update the existing record if exist in DB else It will create new record with ADDRESS_TYPE of BI. Refer hibernate documentation [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#saveOrUpdate(java.lang.Object)).