# saving large object takes too long on hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, blob

I have an object with a Blob column **requestData** and a Text Column "requestDataText" . 
These two fields may hold large Data. In my example , the blob data is around 1.2 MBs and the Text column holds the text equivalent of that Data.

When i try to commit this single entity , it takes around 20 seconds .

```
DBUtil.beginTransaction();
session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
DBUtil.commitTransaction();
```

Is there something wrong or is there a way to shorten this period ?

```
package a.db.entity;
// Generated Feb 22, 2016 11:57:10 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA


/**
 * Foo generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="foo"
    ,catalog="bar"
)
public class Foo  implements java.io.Serializable {
 private Long id;
 private Date reqDate;
 private byte[] requestData;
 private String requestDataText;
 private String functionName;
 private boolean confirmed;
 private boolean processed;
 private boolean errorOnProcess;
 private Date processStartedAt;
 private Date processFinishedAt;
 private String responseText;
 private String processResult;
 private String miscData;

public AsyncRequestLog() {
}


 @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)

@Column(name="Id", unique=true, nullable=false)
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

...

}
```

Comment: If you do this insert from the mysql CLI, does it take roughly the same amount of time? (in which case the issue is the DB, not hibernate. If you can do this from a remote CLI session rather than on the server itself). Is the DB "close" to the application? (just want to be sure that the DB is not on the other side of the world).  I've used Hibernate to store documents on mysql a few years ago and it took milliseconds to store and retrieve them.

Comment: @Augusto the DB is connected via 1Gbit Local Network . I cannot insert via Mysql CLI because of the Blob field

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed you're starting a transaction and then doing a `saveOrUpdate()` which might explain the slow down, as hibernate will try to retrieve the row from the DB first (as explained on this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21535730/608820)).

If you know if the entity is new call `save()` and if you the entity has to be updated call `update()`.

Another suggestion, but I'm not sure if this applies any more to MySQL, try to store the blobs/clobs in a different table from where you store the data, if you are intending to update the blob/clobs. In the past this mix made MySQL run slow as it had to resize the 'block' allocated to a row. So have one table with all the attributes and a different table just for the blob/clob. This is not the case if the table is read-only.

Comment: The BLOB field and the TEXT field are never updated , just read. And there is no performance issue while reading or processing them. I will inspect your "saveOrUpdate" suggestion and provide an update . ty