# Synchronizing Hibernate inserts using guarded block

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, hibernate, concurrency

I am trying to solve a problem with conflicting concurrent database inserts via Hibernate in MySQL.

I have a piece of code that can easily be executed by multiple threads at the same time. It is checking the database for an existence of a record and if it does not exist a new record gets inserted. This same insert-if-nonexistent operation is performed on a related child record. I get a ConstraintViolationException if two threads try to persist the child record at the same time, because both threads see the record does not exist at the moment they are querying it, so both threads attempt to save the same record which violates a unique constraint, and one of them fails.

I am trying to synchronise the query-insert operations on the application level using a guarded block, so that a thread is waiting for another thread to finish inserting the records before querying the database. But even though I see the synchronisation works, querying for the record still returns no results, even if the record has been persisted in another thread. So the constraint violation still happens.

- I am using Hibernate 5.1.0
- I am managing database transactions manually
- I have enabled query cache and second-level cache globally, but am using CacheMode.REFRESH for the SELECT queries
- I am not using optimistic or pessimistic database locking or row versioning.

Here is a code example:

In each synchronized operation I try to persist a Product if it does not exist, and a related parent Supplier if it does not exist.

```
public class UpdateProcessor extends HttpServlet {

  // Indicator used for synchronizing read-insert operations
  public static Boolean newInsertInProgress = false;

  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    Session hbSession = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
      hbSession = HibernateUtils.getNewSession();

      UpdateProcessor.waitForInsert(); // if there is an insert in progress, wait for it to finish
      UpdateProcessor.notifyInsertStarted(); // obtain lock

      tx = hbSession.beginTransaction();

      Product existingProduct = findProductBySKU(sku);
      if(existingProduct == null) {

        Product newProduct = new Product();
        newProduct.setSKU(sku);

        Supplier existingSupplier = findSupplierByName(name);
        if(existingSupplier == null) {
          Supplier newSupplier = new Supplier();
          newSupplier.setName(name);
          db.save(newSupplier);
          newProduct.setSupplier(newSupplier);
        } else {
          newProduct.setSupplier(existingSupplier);
        }

        db.save(newProduct);
      }

      tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception t) {
      // <rollback transaction>
      response.sendError(500);
    } finally {

      // Safeguard to avoid thread deadlock - release lock always, if obtained
      if(UpdateProcessor.newInsertInProgress) {
            UpdateProcessor.notifyInsertFinished(); // release lock and notify next thread
      }

      // <close session>
    }
  }

  private static synchronized void waitForInsert() {
    if(!UpdateProcessor.newInsertInProgress) {
        log("Skipping wait - thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        return;
    }
    while(UpdateProcessor.newInsertInProgress) {
        boolean loggedEntering = false;
        if(!loggedEntering) {
            log("Entering wait - thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            loggedEntering = true;
        }
        try {
            UpdateProcessor.class.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    log("Exiting wait - thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - " + System.currentTimeMillis());
  }

  private static synchronized void notifyInsertStarted() {
    UpdateProcessor.newInsertInProgress = true;
    UpdateProcessor.class.notify();
    log("Notify start - thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - " + System.currentTimeMillis());
  }

  private static synchronized void notifyInsertFinished() {
    UpdateProcessor.newInsertInProgress = false;
    UpdateProcessor.class.notify();
    log("Notify finish - thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - " + System.currentTimeMillis());
  }
}
```

The output after concurrently making the request:

```
Skipping wait - thread 254 - 1478171162713
Notify start - thread 254 - 1478171162713
Entering wait - thread 255 - 1478171162713
Entering wait - thread 256 - 1478171162849
Notify finish - thread 254 - 1478171163050
Exiting wait - thread 255 - 1478171163051
Notify start - thread 255 - 1478171163051
Entering wait - thread 256 - 1478171163051
Error - thread 255:
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '532-supplier-name-1' for key 'supplier_name_uniq'
```

Persisting the new supplier record still threw an exception in thread 255 because the unique constraint (id, name) is violated.

Why is the SELECT still not returning any records after a synchronized insert? Is guarded lock a correct way to avoid the multi-insert problem?

Comment: Have you tried flushing the Hibernate session after save? hSession.flush()

Comment: Yes, even with flushing manually it still throws the exception. The committing of the transaction (tx.commit()) also flushes behind the scenes.

Comment: Just for the sake of completion, can you disable your cache, all caches, and try?

Comment: I disabled the query cache and second-level cache with the config properties:

hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache="false"; 

hibernate.cache.use_query_cache="false".

Also set CacheMode to IGNORE for the selects. Still same result..

Comment: Last thing i wanted to check is what happens if you move obtaining the Session AFTER UpdateProcessor.notifyInsertStarted(); // obtain lock

Comment: Not sure if `saveOrUpdate` instead of `save` helps?

Comment: @Mechkov Wrapping the entire session block (creation to closing) fixes the issue! So that means that session state is not synced between threads, as I understand it? Can I close the session outside of the synchronised block? I am asking because in my actual code, after doing this insert operation I do some more database queries and updates, and I need a session for them. I'd rather not recreate the session, if possible.

Comment: @BretC I don't think saveOrUpdate() would work - see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443672/hibernate-saveorupdate-behavior). If the entity I am calling saveOrUpdate on has no id field set, it will try to save it instead of updating, causing the same problem). I don't know the id, I am searching the record by a different field.

Comment: You should be able to close outside, yes. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mechkov's answer above:

Short answer: I needed to include the Hibernate session creation in the synchronised piece of code.

Long answer:
The guarded block properly synchronised the query-insert block but the problem was that even though one thread finishes persisting the records, the second thread cannot see the change in the database until a fresh Hibernate session is created. So the effects of concurrent database modifications are not immediately visible to all threads. An up-to-date database state is obtained via creating a session AFTER an insert is made in some other thread. Including the session creation in the synchronised code ensures that is the case.