# Composite key alternatives in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, csv

In one of the components of my application I have to deal with data which comes from a set of csv files (where content is added and updated over time) and store it into db to a very plain table with Hibernate. The data itself lacks of unique value which is suitable for use as a primary key, but the uniqueness could be achieved with a composite key instead. I'd like to get rid of composite key which was used as a temporary solution. Is there an idiomatic way to do this, keeping an entity objects behave the same way?
The first thing which came to my mind is some hash based solution, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want to achieve. Why not just use an autogenerated ID?

Comment: As I've described there's a bunch of fields which together used as a composite key. And when  saveOrUpdate is called I'd like to update table row where the combination of these values is already present in the table or insert a new row if the combination is unique.

Comment: OK. But how does that prevent you from using an autogenerated ID? You can still use a query to find if a row with the given composite key exists or not, and use the ID everywhere else to uniquely identify a row.

Comment: That's fair, but I was thinking about keeping pretty much same semantics as I'd utilize in case of the composite key. So in a proposed solution I suppose I have to distinguish if the record should be saved or updated explicitly.

Comment: you have to distinguish between a create/update anyway - if creating an object, `persist()` should be called. Otherwise you have to `find()` your object and update it

Comment: @paranoidAndroid, couldn't I just get the session and call `.saveOrUpdate(entity)`?

Comment: @Andrey I thought you are coding to the standard JPA. If you are using specific Hibernate APIs I guess you could. Anyway I think the hash between the keys could work, but you are risking a collision. What is the composite key composed from? which datatypes?

Comment: @Andrey BTW im not sure at all about the  `saveOrUpdate()`. I read a bit of their docs now and i dont think it works the way you think it is - if you create a new, detached instance from the data you read from your CSV, hibernate will think it's a new instance and will try to INSERT it anyway. It works only if your object has the persistence ID (which you get after persist, find etc). In other words - hibernate will not execute a query just to find out if this object is already in the DB. More info here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443672/hibernate-saveorupdate-behavior

Comment: @paranoidAndroid, you're right `jpa` tag seems to be confusing there, it's better to remove it then. Well, hash collisions is an exact thing which makes me doubt about using this approach. And a composite key consists of `String` fields only.

Comment: @paranoidAndroid thanks it seems `.merge()` suits this case.