# How Hibernate SaveOrUpdate(beanobject) method identifies that the given beanobject exist or not

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I would like to know how Hibernate session identifies whether an object is already present in DB or not.
Because in my case a new record is always saved and not updated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6443736/2090568 you should look at this answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate saveOrUpdate behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443672/hibernate-saveorupdate-behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of I know, hibernate Session will get identify the object based on the Primary Key column. Let's say for example, ID is the primary key column in a table and you have set some value to the ID parameter of passing object. Session will check in the mapped table ID value exist or not. If exists, it will call the update(object) otherwise save(object) methods accordingly.

For more information refer this [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#saveOrUpdate(java.lang.Object)) link.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why, you always end up with a save on a new record is because the persistence provider is always treating that object as `TRANSIENT`. And when one is passsed to save or update, it is not yet in the persistence context and hibernate tries to generate an id for it (if `@GeneratedValue` is used) and add that object / entity to the persistence context from which point it has become managed.

This is the snippet from the 5.x hibernate impl:

```
public class DefaultSaveEventListener extends DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener {

protected Serializable performSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) {
    EntityEntry entry = event.getSession().getPersistenceContext().getEntry( event.getEntity() );
    if ( entry!=null && entry.getStatus() != Status.DELETED ) {
        return entityIsPersistent(event);
    }
    else {
        return entityIsTransient(event);
    }
}
```

in your case the `EntityEntry entry` is resolved as null and `entityIsTransient(event);` is invoked. Which contains this:

```
Serializable id = saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId( event );

source.getPersistenceContext().reassociateProxy( event.getObject(), id );
```

which is exactly what i pointed out before.