# Issue with updating JSON logs in Springboot REST Api using PUT

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to update JSON logs in Springboot REST Api using PUT mapping method but the program/code ends up saving a new instance into the Database instead of updating the existing one. I am using the saveOrUpdate method of the currentSession in my DAO implementatioo. Please check out my codes:

DAO implementation class

```
package com.dafe.spring.applogger.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity.UserLog;

@Repository
public class UserLogDaoHibernateImplementation implements UserLogDAO {


    //define field for entity manager
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    //set up constructor injection
    @Autowired
    public UserLogDaoHibernateImplementation(EntityManager theEntityManager) {

    entityManager= theEntityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserLog> findAll() {

        //get the current hibernate session from entity manager
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);


        //create a query
        Query <UserLog> theQuery = 
                currentSession.createQuery("from UserLog", UserLog.class);

        //execute query and get result list

        List<UserLog> userLog = theQuery.getResultList();

        //return the results

        return userLog;
    }

    @Override
    public UserLog findById(int theId) {

        //get the current session
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        //get the userLog
        UserLog theUserLog = 
                currentSession.get(UserLog.class, theId);


        //return the userLog

        return theUserLog;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(UserLog theUserLog) {
        //get the current session
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

        //save
    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theUserLog);

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int theId) {
        //get the current hibernate session
                Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

    //delete object with userid
                Query theQuery = 
                        currentSession.createQuery("delete from UserLog where id=:theUserId");

                theQuery.setParameter("theUserId", theId);

                theQuery.executeUpdate();

    }

}
```

My rest controller class

```
package com.dafe.spring.applogger.rest;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.dafe.spring.applogger.entity.UserLog;
import com.dafe.spring.applogger.service.UserLogService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserLogRestController {

        private UserLogService userLogService;

    //inject logDao using constructor injection
        @Autowired
    public UserLogRestController(UserLogService theUserLogService) {

            userLogService = theUserLogService;
    }

    //expose logs and return list of logs
    @GetMapping("/userLog")
    public List<UserLog> findAll(){

        return userLogService.findAll();
    }


    //add mapping for GET userLog/{UserId}

    @GetMapping("/userLog/{theUserId}")
    public UserLog getUserLog(@PathVariable int theUserId) {

        UserLog theUserLog = userLogService.findById(theUserId);
        if (theUserLog==null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("User Id not found - " + theUserId);
            }
    return theUserLog;  
    }

//add mapping POST for a new user
@PostMapping("/userLog")
public UserLog addUser(@RequestBody UserLog theUserLog)
{

    //just in case they pass an id in JSoN...set id to 0
    //this is to force a save of new item instead of update
    theUserLog.setId(0);
    userLogService.save(theUserLog);

    return theUserLog;
    }


//add mapping for PUT/userLog to update existing user

 @PutMapping("/userLog")
public UserLog updateUserLog(@RequestBody UserLog theUserLog){


    userLogService.save(theUserLog);

    return theUserLog;
}


}
```

Please help me figure this out. Am a newbie in springboot CRUD Rest APIs. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate saveOrUpdate behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443672/hibernate-saveorupdate-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

You must provide value for Id along other fields in your "UserLog" class for updates to happen.

saveOrUpdate() - JPA calls either save or update based on value for Id field in entity class. if value for Id in entity class in is null then jpa calls save() which means it will create a new entry in table otherwise it updates. So provide value for Id in entity class for update.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by provide value for I’d in entity class. I have getter and setter for Id in entity class. Thanks

Comment: You have to provide the value for @Id annotation field in entity class and the that value should exist in table.

Comment: The Id value exists in my database as it does exists in the entity.