# Can I continue a transactional operation after catching an exception?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions

My code looks something like this:

```
@Transactional
public void save(Citizen citizen){
    this.saveCitizen(citizen);
}

private void saveCitizen(Citizen citizen){
    try{
        citizenReposiory.save(citizen);
    } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException exception){
          //Exception on the line below
          Citizen existingCitizen = citizenReposiory.findById(citizen.getId());
          exisitingCitizen.setAge(50);
    }
}
```

I'm first trying to save the citizen. If the exception is thrown it's because the citizen already exists in the database. In this case I want to update the existing row instead. However, in the code above I will get another exception when calling `citizenReposiory.findById(citizen.getId());`. Here's a snippet of the terminal:

```
[26-04-2020 00:35] WARN  [o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]  - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
[26-04-2020 00:35] ERROR [o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper]  - Duplicate entry '10-2020-1' for key 'UKe4wgjj1wdqag5qhbcgnxhbvuj'
[26-04-2020 00:35] ERROR [org.hibernate.AssertionFailure]  - HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred 
(this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): 
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in dk.rsyd.mature.entities.WeeklyCare entry (don't flush the 
Session after an exception occurs)
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in dk.rsyd.mature.entities.WeeklyCare entry (don't flush the 
Session after an exception occurs)
```

What is happening here? Is it not possible to continue with an transaction after catching an exception? I have tried to add `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach could be used. That is, you could first perform the ***findByID***, and verify that the findByID returns a value, if it returns a value, and therefore it already exists, you can carry out the ***setAge*** operation, otherwise you can ***save*** the citizen. In this way you will always do a preliminary check and avoid saving an object that does not exist by going in exception.

Comment: I was just in the middle of rewriting my code to do exactly that. It seems like the other approach is not possible for some reason :)

Comment: Great,!if you solve,you  should close the topic ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If "The Citizen Object" that you submit to citizenReposiory.save() already have the primary key inside. Maybe you can just call saveOrUpdate() simply.

```
private void saveCitizen(Citizen citizen){

    citizenReposiory.saveOrUpdate(citizen);

}
```

FYI

1. [Hibernate saveOrUpdate behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443672/hibernate-saveorupdate-behavior)
2. [Hibernate save() and saveOrUpdate() methods](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-save-and-saveorupdate/)