# How to update in hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

When I entered a new data for a registration id CL123 where the registration id is a priamary key and I called the following method it would entered successfully into the database with a Status as 'FRESH'. If I want to update this particular registration id by calling the same method also it would work fine but now I want to update it with a Status as "DUPLICATE". How to do? Please help me..

```
public Integer savecertificate(Certification certification) {
     Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
     session.beginTransaction();
     certification.setRegID("CL123");
     certification.setClass("M.Sc");
     certification.setStatus("FRESH");

     //certification.setStatus("DUPLICATE");

     session.saveOrUpdate(certification);
     session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Comment: To update fetch first by id and update status and save.

Comment: Well in my case i don't to fetch because it works whether if i want to insert a new data or update the existing data

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another method for update like below.

```
public Integer updateCertificate(Certification certification) {
     Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
     session.beginTransaction();
     certification.setRegID("CL123");
     //certification.setStatus("FRESH");

     certification.setStatus("DUPLICATE");

     session.saveOrUpdate(certification);
     session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

FYI... Hibernate will check the Database with the same id(primary key) if that exist then it will update or it create a new record in the database.

Visit this [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443672/hibernate-saveorupdate-behavior) Link

Comment: Yes where you created your persistence(DB) logic

Comment: From the controller method I call the savecertificate() method as unitservice.savecertificate(certification) ......so if call the updateCertification() method after the savecertificate() won't there will be a clash ?

Comment: You need to call if it is really required. Lets say once u inserted and immediately u need to update then call that update method.

Comment: Like even for a data that i dont want to update it will insert the status as "DUPLICATE"

Comment: It is not really required all the time but sometimes it is. How will i call it when it is required only sometime?

Comment: In a single transaction you can't make insert and update at the same time. So you need to create a new Transaction every time if you want to perform any new operation

Comment: The problem is that i dont a have a specific page for updating. I have a page that can do inserting only. From that inserting page I can do updating also.So that inserting page is calling a controller method that calls the savecertificate method.

Comment: yes in that case once you insert the data come to controller and call the update method again to update the data into db

Comment: u mean in that controller i will call first the save method and then call the update method?

Comment: Yes u need to do that

Comment: But what if i insert a new data? The final status of this data will be "DUPLICATE" which i dont want since an update method also has been called in that controller

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem. Here it is

```
    public Integer savecertificate(Student info) {
         Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
         session.beginTransaction();

         String hql = "Select status from Student where regid='CL123'";
         SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(hql);
         query.setParameter("info", info);
         List<String> status=query.list();

         certification.setRegID("CL123");
         certification.setClass("M.Sc");
         if(status.isEmpty){
            certification.setStatus("FRESH");
         }
         else{
            certification.setStatus("DUPLICATE");
         }

         session.saveOrUpdate(certification);
         session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

It works perfectly